# When create the SharePoint Team Site, the workflow history list is missing

Tags: workflow

Create a SharePoint team site, find that there is no workflow history list. lists/workflow history. any idea?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually want to create workflow association automatically with a list when activate the custom feature, but could not find the workflow history when create the workflow association which will specify the workflow tasks list and workflow history list, the workflow tasks list could be created after activating "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure", but the workflow history list is not provisioned. There is a featured named "WorkflowHistoryList" already activated at the site level then i create a OOTB workflow instance, the workflow histroy list is provisioned.Whic

Comment: Hi..., If you had associated a workflow with the list and started the workflow... It automatically creates the list named 'Workflow History' in your site.

Comment: Thank you. Yes,you are right, i mentioned it too. "manually create OOTB workflow instance" will create the workflow history list. But i wanna all process programmatically then write the code above. :)

Comment: ChrisBao: Please edit your original question, rather than add further information in the form of an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, that list is created only when you use "publishing with workflow" site template because this template creates pages library and associates an approval workflow with the library.

In other words, that list is created only when the site definition/template associates a workflow with workflow enabled objects like lists and libraries. If the site definition does not associate a workflow as part of its definition, the workflow history list will not be created and that is an expected behavior.